# I remembered to bring my books and I remember bringing my books. What is the difference between the two?

Tags: gerunds, infinitives

I remembered to bring my books and I remember bringing my books. What is the difference between the two?

I have been searching for the difference between the two sentences but to no avail. Can someone help me understand, please.

Answer (score 1):

Look at these two examples:

**I remembered to bring my books today after leaving them at home last week.**

The speaker uses the past tense because it was earlier that s/he remembered to take the books with her.

**I remember bringing my books with me this morning but I don't know where I put them.**

The speaker recalls now that s/he brought the books along but can't recall where s/he left them.

So the contexts are different and the choice of which construction to use depends on which better fits what the speaker wants to convey.

In the first instance, the speaker reports that s/he remembered (past tense) when s/he left home to bring her books with her.

In the second, the speaker states that s/he (now - present tense) recalls bringing the books along but doesn't know where they are.

Answer (score 0):

*I remembered to bring my books* means that you didn't forget them (accidentally leave them at home).

*I remember bringing my books* means that you now have a memory of picking up the books and carrying them with you.